# Why the spring on (-) polarity at the alkaline battery 1.5v gets eroded

Tags: battery-chemistry, alkaline

I have small toy and it’s not used for three weeks, later I found out one side of the battery holder at (-) negative polarity spring got eroded. I knew battery gets discharged without using the device but how come the chemical reaction occurred and  entire spring disintegrated?

[image: Battery got discharged and eroded the spring]

Comment: My guess: You have been using cheap zinc-carbon batteries (with the text "heavy duty") on them. They have leaked, because they are terrible. Next time, use alkalines.

Comment: Alkaline batteries are also prone to leaking especially Duracells.I have had a number of good flashlights ruined by alkaline batteries leaking and swelling so they can't be removed.

Comment: True enough. While "heavy duty" batteries will leak, alkalines may also leak. In either case, it's good practice to remove the cells from a device before storing it.

Comment: Well I used Alkaline batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The quality of batteries. Branded batteries can be of bad quality. Be cautious of *Panosanic* or *Sanio* batteries;
2. Damaged batteries, e.g. the parcel full of batteries have fallen to the floor during transportation, and interior and exterior battery structures get damaged, causing the leak shortly;
3. The position of storage. Note that third battery did not leak, because it is located upside down.

The pic of the batteries would help to diagnose the problem better.